# how to make a predefined pakage to subscribe a topic?

Tags: ros, subscribe, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
hello, 
        I want to know that how can i force a predefined package to subscribe a particular topic, for an instance, i have a package named "executive_usarsim" by makokal which acts as an interface between usarsim and ROS and currently it is not subscribing to cmd_vel topic, i want this package to subscribe to "cmd_vel" topic.
Thank you.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194744/how-to-make-a-predefined-pakage-to-subscribe-a-topic?/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose you have no access to the code of the package "executive_usarsim". (in that case it would be really strightforward)

If you have no access then you could remap the output of a specific topic to your desired topic (/cmd_vel) in your launch file.
[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/51077/remap-include/) is an example which coudl be helpful to you. Your keyword shuld be "remap". Since the documentatin in ROS is not so good I suggest to look in existing codes in the Q&A.
Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-14**:
Thank you very much @Andromeda :)